# React error even though syntax is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have removed all my code down to the point I just have this:

```
export class DateApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dateApp">
        <h1> Comments </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
export default DateApp;
```

I get this error on this line:

`Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

point to the `<` on the first `<div>`

I thought it may be a syntax error in one of my functions but as I have removed them all it cant be that.
I have babel, react all installed etc.

Comment: Are you using babel to transpile ES6?

Comment: Do you have `transform-react-jsx` babel plugin installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using babel to transpile to code:

In the root of your project change the `.babelrc` file to include the `react` preset:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

Install the babel react preset using NPM:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
```